# GWT frontend locked during RPC call

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt, locking, rpc

I'm writing a GWT application and encountered a problem that disturbs the user experience massively.

When i login on my website everything works fine at first but after a few clicks every call ends up loading for ages and my loading overlay is visible for a long time (20 seconds - several minutes). First i thought it's my back-end or my server might be overloaded but i realized that the call continues once my pictures on the website are loaded and my logs don't show any evidence of unusually high loading times on that side. It also only occurs when my internet connection is slow, therefore it doesn't happen all the time and it never happens when i test it locally.

My assumption now is that my browser (Chrome 52, haven't tested on other browsers yet) is waiting for some connections to finish before it starts with a new one and therefore blocks any possible interaction.

Anyone with similar experiences or an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: RPC is asynchronous. The problem is somewhere in your code.

Comment: its seems the problem is somewhere in your code.. r u writing the RPC call inside the rpc ?post u r code which creates the issues

Comment: Use ChromeDevTools to profile the RPC call. You can see if the request takes so long or maybe the de-serialization

Comment: I know RPC is asynchronous, but maybe something system-wise is blocking it to execute. since it's a internal software i can't really show you much pieces of code. but i checked my server-side log and it showed the following: 

at first the user right is checked, which happened 09:16:53.776
then the widget is created. in the constructor i init the widget and after that apart from assigning a couple values and doing some ifs i start my first RPC call, logged at 09:16:57.737. this means there are *4* seconds between two log informations and in client code there is basically nothing done.